# Lua: <expression> expected near 'local'

Tags: lua, opencomputers

I've put the following code in a file for OpenComputers:

```
local mathLib = require("math")
local event = require("event")
local data = require("data")
local modem = require("modem")
local osLib = require("os")
local ioLib = require("io")
local writer = require("component").os_cardwriter
```

However, when I try to run it, it says the following error:

```
Lua: [5:0] <expression> expected near local
```

I've tried removing the `local` parts but that hasn't changed anything.
Other than that, I haven't found anything on the Internet so far on how to fix this issue.

IDE: OCLIDE, ran in OpenComputers
Edit: Turns out removing the imports for math, io, and os fixed it.

Comment: I'm not getting any syntax error from that code, however, I'm not familiar with OpenComputers, so it could have a modified Lua interpreter.

Comment: As far as I know, OpenComputers runs a vanilla version of Lua 5.3, however it has some custom libraries.